# PlatformService on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, endeca

I've installed MDEX version 6.2.1 and PlatformServices version 6.1.1. After I've restarted machine I had 2 service: Endeca JCD and EndecaHTTPservice. Problem is with second one as it fails each time I restart my machine or start service manually. Windows Logs System shows me next message: "The Endeca HTTP service service terminated unexpectedly. It has done this 3 time(s)." If somebody has some experience with this help me please! Thanks!

Comment: I can added that I work with Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Endeca http service is build on top of the Apache Tomcat, if Tomcat fails to start with whatever reason you should be able to see the corresponding log files under endeca's %ENDECA_ROOT%\workspace\logs folder.

It's possible that the service launcher fails before the tomcat can even start logging anythign, in that case Windows event viewer may have some information.

The JCD in the version 6 is kept only for backward compatibility with v5 installs and shouldn't be used in the brand new v6 and above installations.

Comment: Thanks! You are right. In logs files I've found that on my server works yet one app which uses the same port that my Tomcat. Thanks for answer!